# Custom attribute / Directive in Stencil.js

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

Can anyone guide me about this? Can `Stencil.js` add Custom attribute / Directive like Aurelia/Angular to **existing elements** or not?

I don't find any doc about this on their site. Only creating a new component nothing about extending existing elements.

I want to add a custom attribute to `div` or any HTML element Is it possible in [Stencil.js](https://stenciljs.com/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute-based components aren't possible with Stencil. The library implements the [Custom Elements spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements), which only works with tags.

Extending existing elements isn't supported either. The spec allows [extensions of builtins](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example), but it isn't implemented in Stencil and [browser support is limited](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/509#issuecomment-230700060).